ref lost its reactivity in tsx
import { ref } from 'vue'
const Test = () => {
  const msg = ref('I am Brave')
  const changeMsg = () => {
    console.log('aa')
    msg.value = 'I will get everything I want'
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <span>{msg.value}</span>
      <button onClick={changeMsg}>btn</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Test


when I click the button,the function changeMsg excuted, but the view did not change with the click operation
I want to make the view to change when I click the button

Is this inside a script setup?

@typed-sigterm This is incorrect. It has functional components, this is the reason why the OP describes that the component renders. But they are stateless, hence the problem

no, this is in the "Test.tsx", Can't I use the functional component directly in vue project ?

It's like script-setup syntax:
import { ref, defineComponent } from 'vue'

const Test = defineComponent({
    setup() {
        const msg = ref('I am Brave')

        const changeMsg = () => {
            console.log('aa')
            msg.value = 'I will get everything I want'
        } 

        return () => (
            <div>
                <span>{msg.value}</span>
                <button onClick={changeMsg}>btn</button>
            </div>
        );
    },
});

export default Test

Update
Or just wrap in defineComponent function, and return arrow function with jsx
const Test = defineComponent(() => {
    const msg = ref('I am Brave')

    const changeMsg = () => {
      console.log('aa')
      msg.value = 'I will get everything I want'
    }

    return () => (
      <div>
        <span>{msg.value}</span>
        <button onClick={changeMsg}>btn</button>
      </div>
    )
})

